# How to correct this error of 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, ms-office

I'm trying to export **dataGrid** into an **excel** file but I keep getting this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Test.exe
Additional information: Ancien format ou bibliothèque de types non valide.
```

Here's my code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(); //this generates the error
        Workbook wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)Excel.ActiveSheet;
        Excel.Visible = true;
        ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Column1";
        ws.Cells[1, 2] = "Column2";
        ws.Cells[1, 3] = "Column3";
        ws.Cells[1, 4] = "Column4";
        ws.Cells[1, 5] = "Column5";
        for (int j=2; j <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            for(int i= 2; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                ws.Cells[j, i] = dataGridView1.Rows[j-2].Cells[i-1].Value;

            }
        }
```

How to correct this?

---------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------

I tried adding this :

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
```

and it worked, it seems like the problem was due to a language conflict.

Comment: Check what version of the interop you have referenced. Then check the registry HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT --> TypeLib. Look for the PrimaryInteropAssemblyName and ensure you have the same verison registered. If you have 14.0 and 15.0 this could be your issue.

Comment: The program is referencing MicroSoft Office Interop Excel version 12.0.0.0, how do i find that registry? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: Hello, exactly the same. Just check the registry. You can search for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel under the TypeLib key, Use (Ctrl F) for find

Comment: In the registry it says "Version 14.0.0.0", is this the problem? How do I get the same version for both?

Comment: Also it shows me the error in this part of the code: Workbook wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);

Comment: So seems like you are referencing the wrong version. Delete the ref from your project and add a new ref to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll. Also ensure that v14.00 is the only reg entry. Delete the other key for 12 if it exists.

Comment: I'm only getting the 12.0.0.0 version in that path you told me, I have Office11 and Office12, do I need to download something?
I only have version 14.0.0.0 in the registry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142736/discussion-between-wheels73-and-musicisuniversal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried adding this :

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
```

and it worked, it seems like the problem was due to a language conflict.